# How do i get pointers value? C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

So I want to get the value from an item of vector. The vector contains Line items.
Line has to pointers Vertex *p1 and Vertex *p2. and Vertex has fields of x and y. How can i make my code give me the values of those x and y?

```
for(Line<Vertex> line : lines){
    painter.drawLine(line.p1->x + 5, line.p1->y + 5, line.p2->x + 5, line.p2->y + 5);
}
```

Line class is as following:

```
template<class T>
class Line {

public:

    T *p1;
    T *p2;

    Line (T *v1, T *v2)
        : p1(v1),
          p2(v2)
    {}

    Line (const Line& l){
        if(this != &l){
            p1 = l.p1;
            p2 = l.p2;
        }
    }

     Line& operator= (const Line& l) {
        if (this == &l)
            return *this;
        p1 = l.p1;
        p2 = l.p2;
        return *this;
    }

    ~Line (){
    }
};
```

Vertex class:

```
class Vertex {

public:


    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;

    Vertex() = default;
    Vertex(float nx, float ny);

    float distanceFrom(Vertex v);

};
```

Main:

```
std::vector<Line<Vertex>> lines;
Vertex *firstPoint;
Vertex *secondPoint;
bool firstPointChosen = false;
bool secondPointChosen = false;

if(!firstPointChosen){
        for(Vertex vertex : vertices){
            firstPoint = &vertex;
            firstPointChosen = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    else{
        for(Vertex vertex : vertices){
            secondPoint = &vertex;
            secondPointChosen = true;
            break;
        }
    }

if(firstPointChosen && secondPointChosen){
    Line<Vertex> line(firstPoint, secondPoint);
    lines.push_back(line);
    update();
    firstPointChosen = false;
    secondPointChosen = false;
}
for(Line<Vertex> line : lines){
        painter.drawLine(line.p1->x + 5, line.p1->y + 5, line.p2->x + 5, line.p2->y + 5);
    }
```

How do i get make the first block of code return the values of x and y for each line that i have added to the lines vector?

Currently it doesn't return anything or i'm missunderstanding something.

EDIT:
The main class is alot bigger, but it is called in that order. First it chooses the first vertex, then second. If both of them are selected it makes a new Line with those two vertices, but for some reason they get no values or something.

Comment: which is first block?

Comment: How your vertices list is initialized ? More specifically, can you show your vertex constructor because here it seems that x and y are set to 0 in any case

Comment: Vertex::Vertex(float nx, float ny)
    : x {nx}
    , y {ny}
{
}

        std::vector<Vertex> vertices;

        std::vector<Line<Vertex>> lines;

Comment: What do you mean by the first block? THe main class is alot bigger, but it is called in that order. First it chooses the first vertex, then second. If both of them are selected it makes a new Line with those two vertices, but for some reason they get no valuse or something.

Comment: @user3519253 It's unclear what you're asking, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions

Answer (score 0):

it should be the other way:

pointed value of line and member of vertex

```
for(Line<Vertex> line : lines){
    painter.drawLine(line->p1.x + 5, line->p1.y + 5, line->p2.x + 5, line->p2.y + 5);
}
```

if the class has

```
T* pointerToMember;
T member;
```

you should get pointed member with `->`
and member with `.`

```
obj->pointerToMember;
obj.member;
```

Comment: Hum... You are wrong... Choice between . and -> is driven by the left side not by the "member type". His/her code is correct